# シェルスクリプトでcurl -i のheaderとbodyを入れ替えるには

Tags: shellscript, shell

`curl -i` を利用すると以下の出力が得られるようです。

```
status code
header
header
header

body
body
body
```

この最初の `\n\n` を境界として、最終的には以下のような出力を得たいです。
どうすればいいでしょうか。

```
body
body
body

status code
header
header
header
```

できればワンライナー(パイプでつなげる感じで)だと嬉しいです。

Answer (score 3):

以下は awk を使う方法の一例ですが、`RS(Record Separator)` を `HTTP response header` と `response body` の区切り文字列(`\r\n\r\n`) に設定しています。

```
$ curl -s -i https://example.com/ | awk -vRS='\r\n\r\n' 'NR==1{first=$0}NR>1;END{print first}'
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
                :

</body>
</html>

HTTP/2 200 
accept-ranges: bytes
age: 411753
cache-control: max-age=604800
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Tue, 11 Aug 2020 10:22:39 GMT
etag: "3147526947+ident"
expires: Tue, 18 Aug 2020 10:22:39 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
server: ECS (sjc/4E74)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: HIT
content-length: 1256
```

Answer (score 0):

とりあえず書いてみました。もうちょっときれいに書けるかもしれません。

```
$ cat hoge.txt
status code
header
header
header

body
body
body
$ cat hoge.txt | awk '/^$/{f=1;next};{if(!f){d=d $0 "\n"}else{print}};END{printf "\n" d}'
body
body
body

status code
header
header
header
```

sedでも書いてみました。

```
$ cat hoge.txt | sed -e '1,/^$/{/^$/d;H;d}' -e '$G'
body
body
body

status code
header
header
header
```

Comment: うおーすごい、よくよく調べないと私には理解できない難易度ですね。
sedの方は短くていい感じなのでぜひ個別アンサーにしていただけると良いと思いました。(票入れたい)

Comment: sedの処理範囲指定
'1,/xxx/c': 一行目からxxxのパターンがある行までに対してcコマンド, 
’$c': 最後の行に対してcコマンド.

sedのコマンド 
H: 現在のパターンをホールドスペースに追加,
G: ホールドスペースの内容を現在のパターンに追加.

Comment: 票入れたいと思っていただけただけで十分です。ありがとうございます。